# Import data from HTML Excel file using PHP

Tags: php, html, import, xls

I need to import the following excel file content into database using PHP script. It seems the excel file using none-standard format, so what is the best practice to do the task.

```
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>List</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:Selected/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif])-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>&#1585;&#1602;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1591;&#1575;&#1604;&#1576;</th>
            <th>&#1575;&#1587;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1591;&#1575;&#1604;&#1576;</th>
            <th>&#1575;&#1604;&#1581;&#1575;&#1604;&#1577;</th>
            <th>&#1575;&#1604;&#1583;&#1585;&#1580;&#1577;</th>
            <th>&#1605;&#1604;&#1575;&#1581;&#1592;&#1575;&#1578;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2141116724</td>
            <td>&#1588;&#1607;&#1583; &#1587;&#1593;&#1583; &#1605;&#1606;&#1575;&#1581;&#1609;
                &#1575;&#1604;&#1602;&#1581;&#1591;&#1575;&#1606;&#1609; </td>
            <td>&#1605;&#1587;&#1580;&#1604;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>54</td>
            <td>2192131354</td>
            <td>&#1593;&#1584;&#1575;&#1585;&#1610; &#1584;&#1610;&#1575;&#1576; &#1605;&#1581;&#1605;&#1608;&#1583;
                &#1575;&#1604;&#1578;&#1608;&#1581;&#1610;&#1583; </td>
            <td>&#1605;&#1587;&#1580;&#1604;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I used this code to extract the html code, Now need to skip all columns except the second and third col.

```
    $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $file_open = fopen($file,"r");
    $html = file($file);

    preg_match_all('#<tr[^>]*>(.*?)</tr>#is', $html[0], $lines);
    
    $result = array();
    
    foreach ($lines[1] as $k => $line) {
        preg_match_all('#<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>#is', $line, $cell);
    
        foreach ($cell[1] as $cell) {
            $result[$k][] = trim($cell);
        }
    }
    
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: How can you tell it is non-standard? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to extract all TR/TD elements, I need to skip unwanted columns. I just need the second and third columns only.